# Giving wrong output: How to break a string into dictionary words

Tags: c++, string, string-matching

I am trying to implement the solution of breaking a given string into its constituent dictionary words problem, but my code is giving wrong output for strings like "icecreamicecream" wherein I am getting some words twice in the output. Please let me know where I am going wrong. Following is my code:

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 12
using namespace std;
string arr[]={"i", "like", "sam", "sung", "samsung", "mobile", "ice","cream", "icecream", "man", "go", "mango"};
set<string> dictionary (arr,arr+MAX);
int cnt=0;
void print_words(string str,int i,int j)//i and j denote starting and ending indices respectively of the string to be matched
{
    if(i>j||j>=str.length()||i>=str.length())
        {
        return;
        }
    string temp (str, i, j-i+1);
    if(dictionary.find(temp)==dictionary.end())
        print_words(str,i,j+1);
    else
    {
        cout<<temp<<endl;
        cnt++;
        print_words(str,j+1,j+1);
        print_words(str,i,j+1);
    }

}
int main()
{
    string str;
    cin>>str;
    print_words(str,0,0);
    cout<<cnt<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For the string icecreamicecream: I want this to be the order of the output:
i ice cream i ice cream icecream icecream
1st i am finding all words in linear fashion, then backtracking to get the remaining words.

Comment: Your problem has several solutions, but you do not seem to separate them (example solutions: `ice cream ice cream`, `icecream icecream`, `i cream icecream`...).

Comment: According to me the output displayed should be:
i ice cream i ice cream icecream icecream

Comment: You should post what you expect/want in the question (with more details than in your comment).

Comment: Ok, but: this is not a linear search (before the "backtracking"). With a linear search, you will get `i cream` (notice that the `ice` is not present).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution (with not exactly the output you want) [**(live example)**](https://ideone.com/qjlgwl):

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;
string arr[]={"i", "like", "sam", "sung", "samsung", "mobile", "ice","cream", "icecream", "man", "go", "mango"};
set<string> dictionary (arr,arr+MAX);
int cnt=0;

void search_grow(string str, int i, int j)
{
    if(i > j || j >= str.length() || i >= str.length())
    {
        return;
    }

    string temp(str, i, j - i + 1);
    if(dictionary.find(temp) != dictionary.end())
    {
        std::cout << "[search_grow] " << temp << "\n";
        cnt++;
    }
    search_grow(str, i, j + 1);
}

void search_part(string str)
{
    for(int t = 0; t < str.size(); t++)
        search_grow(str, t, t);
}

int main()
{
    string str;
    cin>>str;
        search_part(str);
    cout<<cnt<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Idea: do a linear search (`search_grow()`), by extending at end the string to search in the dictionary, then starting repeating for each position in the string.

Output:

```
[search_grow] i
[search_grow] ice
[search_grow] icecream
[search_grow] cream
[search_grow] i
[search_grow] ice
[search_grow] icecream
[search_grow] cream
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this (using the STL and iterators)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//use a comparison function to define a custom ordering
//by which to order the strings based on length instead
//of by character:
struct CompareStrings {
    bool operator() (const string& s1, const string& s2) {
        return s1.size() < s2.size();
    }
};

int main() {
    const char *arr[] = {"i", "like", "sam", "sung", "samsung", "mobile", "ice","cream", "icecream", "man", "go", "mango"};
    size_t arr_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    //initialize the set with the array and with the custom ordering function:
    set <string, CompareStrings> dictionary (arr, arr+arr_size);
    vector <string> solutions;

    set <string>::iterator it;
    vector <string>::iterator jt;

    string test_string = "icecreamicecream";

    for (it = dictionary.begin(); it != dictionary.end(); ++it) {
        size_t found = test_string.find(*it);

        while (found != string::npos) {
            if (found != string::npos) {
                solutions.push_back(*it);
            }
            found = test_string.find(*it, found+1);
        }
    }

    //iterate over the solutions:
    for (jt = solutions.begin(); jt != solutions.end(); ++jt) {
        cout << *jt << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
i
i
ice
ice
cream
cream
icecream
icecream
```

Note: that the output is ordered this way mainly because the values are stored depending on which element is found first in the set (which itself is determined by how `sets` store their respective values in memory).

UPDATE:

Updated to reflect a custom ordering function.

REFERENCES:

[Sorting a set<string> on the basis of length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844909/sorting-a-setstring-on-the-basis-of-length)